# In Format-Table, how do I remove results with certain words?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a PowerShell that lists every process that isn't required by windows.

---

What I want:

a table without any processes owned by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (as well as names of said process)

---

What I'm getting:

a list of every process, name and username

---

I've tried using cmd, I've tried using TASKLIST (cmdlet), I've tried looking it up but there seems to be nothing about this specifically.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Format-Table -Property Name, UserName
```

It would also be nice to also get rid of processes like system, that have no "username"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply filter the result before your format :

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where UserName -ne "NT AUTHORITY\System"  | Format-Table -Property Name, UserName
```

`-ne` means Non Equal

Comment: Thank you, i was using ne in cmd but couldn't find it in ps